# using mutate_each from dplyr to convert all numeric variables to factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use mutate_each from dplyr to conver ALL the numeric variables of data set in factor.

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
tbl_df(iris) ->iris

# I can transform all variables in factor
iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor)) %>% summary
# I can transform some variables in factor
iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor),one_of("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")) %>% summary
```

but my goal is to tranform all numeric variables to factor so I try this :

```
iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor),sapply(iris,is.numeric)) %>% summary # should be a good way, but it doesn't
```

another try

```
iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor),one_of(names(iris)[sapply(iris,is.numeric)]))
# Error in one_of(vars, ...) : object 'iris' not found

iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor),names(iris)[sapply(iris,is.numeric)])
#Error in one_of(vars, ...) : object 'iris' not found

# anyway the one_of function dont seems to work in mutate_each
vars<-names(iris)[sapply(iris,is.numeric)]
iris %>%   mutate_each_(funs(as.factor),one_of(c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")))
iris %>%   mutate_each_(funs(as.factor),one_of(vars))

# Without %>% This works
mutate_each(iris,funs(as.factor), one_of(c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))) %>% summary
```

It's strange..
Any idea??

thks

Comment: `iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor), which(sapply(., is.numeric))) %>% summary`?

Comment: @jeremycg > iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor), which(sapply(., is.numeric))) %>% summary
Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : object '.' not found

Comment: works for me - do you have `plyr` loaded (you shouldn't)? Up to date with lastest `dplyr` version?

Comment: dplyr 0.4.1 and plyr 1.8.2 ... both loaded. In a New R session I test this : `library(plyr);
library(dplyr);
data(iris);
iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor), which(sapply(., is.numeric))) %>% summary`

Comment: yeah, try updating `dplyr` - 0.4.3 is out, and for me that exact command works in a new session

Comment: If you modify your approach (removing `one_of`), it would also work: `vars <- names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.numeric)]; iris %>% mutate_each_(funs(as.factor), vars) %>% str`

Comment: thks, I updated my package and it's ok. (I'm using RRO, so I had to change the snapshot date : `options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-12-06"))`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

today a better solution should be :

```
iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,as.factor)
```

Comment: How could we filter column names containing string `width` then convert these columns to factor?

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for dplyr version 1.06 and ahead (and a little before this too but I forget the version)

```
iris %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric) , as.factor))
```

`mutate_if()` (and others) have been superseded by `across()` or the `across()` / `where()` combo within mutate.